# Accessing google spreadsheet API restrictions in PHP issue

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api

I've created a spreadsheet, which I managed to successfully update with some data using the [google api](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) library and by creating a `service accounts` credentials from `Google console -> Api & Services -> Credentials`.

My problem is to try to restrict the access of the spreadsheet file. If don't allow to be publicly available for everyone with Editor roles, it will not work. I m getting this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

If I allow for everyone to access my spreadsheet, like in the image below , it will work .
[image]

I am also running my script, which updates the spreadsheet via a cronjob. Also this is the code where I do the auth part and I'm using the data from my `Service Contract`:

```
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets and PHP');
        $configuration = '{
  "type": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['type'].'",
  "project_id": "'.$apiConfig['projectId'].'",
  "private_key_id": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['private_key_id'].'",
  "private_key": "'.$key.'",
  "client_email": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['client_email'].'",
  "client_id": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['client_id'].'",
  "auth_uri": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['auth_uri'].'",
  "token_uri": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['token_uri'].'",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['auth_provider_x509_cert_url'].'",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "'.$apiConfig['keyFile']['client_x509_cert_url'].'"
}';

        $client->setAuthConfig(json_decode($configuration, true));
        $client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        return new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
```

Does anyone have any clue how can I restrict the access? and still have this work?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it work by adding this email address :
[image]

To the `Share with people and groups`. See image from my post(question) .